# How to send encoded Base64 image string to server using JSON object

Tags: android

I am new in android . i have send image to server using Json format as a string.

so i have Encoded image string  i.e base64 string.

```
 Json j =  new JSonObject();

String Image_string = Base64.ToEncodedString(bytearray, Base64.Default);

j.put("image_file_content",Image_string);
```

But i am getting this error.
 Please help me..wts wrong

400 Bad Request

## Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found

error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: make sure you are passing correct URL, 404 comes when you have done mistake in your URL or web server is not working properly.

Comment: Do you a definition of this API to append to your post? It sounds.. odd and wasteful.. to use JSON to post large binary content to a web server.

Comment: try new String(decoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); or new String(decoded, Charset.forName("UTF-8") );

Comment: Base64.encodeBase64 it requires java 7 then it will be properly encoded to base64. and for Java 8 you can use BaseEncoder http://stackoverflow.com/a/28305759/3496570

Answer (score 2):

Consider using URLEncoder

```
URLEncoder.encode("String to encode", "UTF-8");
```

Check out the docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html