# Base64 Java encode and decode a string

Tags: java, base64, decode, encode

I want to encode a string into `base64` and transfer it through a socket and decode it back.

But after decoding it gives different answer.

Following is my code and result is "77+9x6s="

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

    public class f{

       public static void main(String a[]){

          String str = new String(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("user:123"));
          String res = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(str.getBytes());
          System.out.println(res);
       }
    }
```

Any idea about how to implement this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java

Comment: `DataTypeConverter` works just fine, the original poster has just mixed the order. It should look like this:

`String str = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary("user:123".getBytes());`
`String res = new String(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(str));`

Comment: parseBase64Binary() is used for decoding and printBase64Binary() is used for encoding.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

You can use following approach:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

// Encode data on your side using BASE64
byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(str.getBytes());
System.out.println("encoded value is " + new String(bytesEncoded));

// Decode data on other side, by processing encoded data
byte[] valueDecoded = Base64.decodeBase64(bytesEncoded);
System.out.println("Decoded value is " + new String(valueDecoded));
```

Hope this answers your doubt.

Comment: I get `The method encodeBase64(byte[]) is undefined for the type Base64`

Comment: This one is better http://stackoverflow.com/a/13862852/2615737

Comment: String str =Base64.encodeToString(strFinalXML.getBytes(), 0); //For java 1.7 +

Comment: please specify the version of Java for this solution, as new functionality was given to Java 8 but it was diffrent in 6 & 7.

Comment: Which Base64 library did you use? There are many.

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales He's using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

Comment: This answer is somewhat confusing when using Java 8 as this now includes a Base64 class but does not have the method "encodeBase64". The library that this answer is using is not stated in the answer. If you are using Java 8+ then better to follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28305759/236587

Comment: @RupertMadden-Abbott encodeBase64 is not available under package java.util.Base64.

To have above code working, You have to import Base64 from org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

Answer (score 163):

Java 8 now supports BASE64 Encoding and Decoding. You can use the following classes:
`java.util.Base64`, `java.util.Base64.Encoder` and `java.util.Base64.Decoder`.

Example usage:

```
// encode with padding
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(someByteArray);

// encode without padding
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(someByteArray);

// decode a String
byte [] barr = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
```

Comment: When to use with padding vs without padding??

Comment: Take care when switching from apache to java 8: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64 also accepts mime encoded input, but java.util.Base64.getDecoder not. If you also want to decode mime encoded you need to use java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky here is the anwer to what is padding? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080988/why-does-base64-encoding-require-padding-if-the-input-length-is-not-divisible-by It has to do with filling the String with 0 bytes if its odd

Answer (score 63):

The accepted answer uses the Apache Commons package but this is how I did it using Java's native libraries

**Java 11 and up**

```
import java.util.Base64;

public class Base64Encoding {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base64.Encoder enc = Base64.getEncoder();
        Base64.Decoder dec = Base64.getDecoder();
        String str = "77+9x6s=";

        // encode data using BASE64
        String encoded = enc.encodeToString(str.getBytes());
        System.out.println("encoded value is \t" + encoded);

        // Decode data
        String decoded = new String(dec.decode(encoded));
        System.out.println("decoded value is \t" + decoded);
        System.out.println("original value is \t" + str);
    }
}
```

**Java 6 - 10**

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;    
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class EncodeString64 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String str = "77+9x6s=";
        // encode data using BASE64
        String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(str.getBytes());
        System.out.println("encoded value is \t" + encoded);

        // Decode data 
        String decoded = new String(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encoded));
        System.out.println("decoded value is \t" + decoded);

        System.out.println("original value is \t" + str);
    }
}
```

The better way would be to `try/catch` the encoding/decoding steps but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Note that this will not work on Android.

Comment: Note that javax.xml.bind (JAXB) is removed in Java 11.

Comment: Updated. Thanks, Dennie.

Comment: `java.util.Base64` is available starting Java 8, not 11.

Answer (score 27):

For Spring Users , Spring Security has a Base64 class in the `org.springframework.security.crypto.codec` package that can also be used for encoding and  decoding of Base64.
Ex.

```
 public static String base64Encode(String token) {
    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encode(token.getBytes());
    return new String(encodedBytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}


public static String base64Decode(String token) {
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(token.getBytes());
    return new String(decodedBytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}
```

Comment: For those of you who are looking this now 'org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.Base64' is deprecated

Answer (score 24):

The following is a good solution -

```
import android.util.Base64;

String converted = Base64.encodeToString(toConvert.toString().getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

String stringFromBase = new String(Base64.decode(converted, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

That's it. A single line encoding and decoding.

Comment: it is renamed to java.util.Base64.

Comment: great solution without any libraries!

Answer (score 8):

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class f{

   public static void main(String a[]){

      String str = new String(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(new String("user:123").getBytes()));
      String res = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(str);
      System.out.println(res);
   }
}
```