# Trying to duplicate api authentication from iOS app into java, don't userstand code

Tags: java, c#, ios, cocoa-touch

Im trying to port an app from iOS to java but the docs are pretty broken, I was given a sample bit of code that is used to authenticate the user.

**"To authentication, the HTTP Header "Authorization" must be set with the 
value "Basic base64encodedValue" where base64encodedValue is the string of "email:password" 
(the user's email and password) encoded in base 64. The authorization call in objective-c looks like 
the following:"**

```
- (void)setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)

password {

NSString *basicAuthCredentials = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, password];

[self setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", 

AFBase64EncodedStringFromString(basicAuthCredentials)] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

}
```

**Returns
authentication_token - This token needs to be supplied to the methods in the HTTP 
Header "Authorization""**

The wording is strange so is this just adding a generic header to the http request?
is the key for the header request "Authorization" with a value of the base64 encoded "username:password"

or is the key actually "Basic base64encodedValue" ?

or is it actually sending basic authenitcation with the request?

Comment: This might help with working with Base64 string; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743851/base64-java-encode-and-decode-a-string
 My guess is it's setting the Authorization header with a base64 encoded value which is the value of "email:password". The heard is sent with the HTTP request.

Comment: I know how to base64 encode a string, im asking what headers is this code snippet adding to the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It adds the concatenation of 'Basic ' and the base64 value of email:password, where email and password are specific to each user.

In a simple pseudocode, the header is formed like this:

`header = 'Basic ' + base64(email:password)`

That is the value. The key is 'Authorization'

Comment: Ok, I see that makes sense, they used too many quotes I couldn't tell what was supposed to be a literal string. One last thing is AFBase64EncodedStringFromString in any way different than any other base64 encoding scheme. Will it be the same as java, php, etc??

Comment: Don't know, I never used it personally. But I expect it's the same.