# How to compare base64 data in database with binary data?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

Due to some project requirement I have to convert my DB `VARCHAR` data into `base64(VARBINARY)`. Now the problem is that while I am trying to query DB from my java application using:

```
criteria.createCriteria("parties").add(Restrictions.ilike("name", "%"+ "james".getBytes() +"%"));
```

My query returns me `null` while I already have base64 representation of `james` in my DB name column. Why?

Comment: shouldn't you convert james to base64 encoding instead of getting the raw bytes?

Comment: don't have that option , because can't break the existing code

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743851/base64-java-encode-and-decode-a-string)

Try something like this:

```
criteria.createCriteria("parties").add(
    Restrictions.ilike(
      "name",
      "%"+ new String(Base64.encodeBase64("james".getBytes())) +"%"));
```

Comment: This won't work unless there are a multiple of 3 characters before "james" in the decoded text.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, could you comment on that? I'm not into base64 encoding myself. Why multiple of 3 characters are required?

Comment: `base64_encode("james")` returns `amFtZXM=` ; `base64_encode("ajames")` returns `YWphbWVz` ; `base64_encode("abjames")` returns `YWJqYW1lcw==` ; `base64_encode("abcjames")` returns `YWJjamFtZXM=`. Look at the first and the last one. You'll see the first result in the 4th. Do you see the first result in the 2nd or 3rd result ?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire good point. So that makes like search practically impossible unless the whole dataset is padded?