# Simple encryption in java-no key/password

Tags: java, string, algorithm, encryption, random

Say I have an IP address, 192.168.1.1

I want my program to create a random one-word string based on this IP address which can be easily decrypted without a key or password or additional security.

eg.

> I enter 192.168.1.1
>
> Program converts it to AzlQrEHCSD or some other random string
>
> I enter this string in the program
>
> It gets converted back to 192.168.1.1

Is there any simple algorithm that can do this without generating stuff like keys or additional passwords? I understand that keys and passwords are **a must** for encryption and decryption, but my scenario does not require it.

Comment: How about Base64 encoding?

Comment: It will be not encryption at all, just encoding. Convert your ip to bytes and apply base64 conversion

Comment: xor encryption is fast and easy to implement.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know its overkill but i would use [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) library since its realy easy to use. All you need is random seed to encrypt or decrpyt.

Here is the source code for encrypting data:

```
String seed = "ipNumber";
String myIpValue = "192.168.0.1";

StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
encryptor.setPassword(seed);
String encrypted= encryptor.encrypt(myIpValue);
```

And for data decryption:

```
StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
encryptor.setPassword(seed);

String decrypted = encryptor.decrypt(encrypted);
```

Or you could just encode or decode your string to base64 example is show here:
[Base64 Java encode and decode a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743851/base64-java-encode-and-decode-a-string)

Answer (score 9):

Almost the same as `higuaro` solutions but with a lot of fixes to make it work, the following code tested and working since `higuaro` not working well like characters went into numbers and when you reverse its get single number and damage everything:

```
public String caesarCipherEncrypt(String plain) {
   String b64encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(plain.getBytes());

   // Reverse the string
   String reverse = new StringBuffer(b64encoded).reverse().toString();

   StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
   final int OFFSET = 4;
   for (int i = 0; i < reverse.length(); i++) {
      tmp.append((char)(reverse.charAt(i) + OFFSET));
   }
   return tmp.toString();
}
```

To de-crypt procede backwards:

```
public String caesarCipherDecrypte(String secret) {
   StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
   final int OFFSET = 4;
   for (int i = 0; i < secret.length(); i++) {
      tmp.append((char)(secret.charAt(i) - OFFSET));
   }

   String reversed = new StringBuffer(tmp.toString()).reverse().toString();
   return new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(reversed));
}
```

I hope its helpful.

Comment: There is no variable ``key`` in here: ``key.charAt(i)``, didn't you mean ``secret.charAt(i)`` ?

Comment: @JagodaSokół yes, ty

Comment: What's more, I also changed: ``Base64.getDecoder()`` to ``Base64.getMimeDecoder()``, due to ``Base64: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character`` error and included your functions in my small university project :)

Answer (score 4):

You can encode the ip `String` to `base64`, reverse the string, and then use a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher):

```
public String easeyEncrypt(String ip) {
   String b64encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(ip);

   // Reverse the string
   String reverse = new StringBuffer(b64encoded).reverse().toString();

   StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
   final int OFFSET = 4;
   for (int i = 0; i < reverse.length(); i++) {
      tmp.append(reverse.charAt(i) + OFFSET);
   }
   return tmp.toString();
}
```

To decrypt procede backwards:

```
public String easeyDecrypt(String secret) {
   StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
   final int OFFSET = 4;
   for (int i = 0; i < secret.length(); i++) {
      tmp.append(secret.charAt(i) - OFFSET);
   }

   String reversed = new StringBuffer(tmp.toString()).reverse().toString();
   return Base64.encode(reversed);
}
```

Comment: From the wikipedia link: As with all single-alphabet substitution ciphers, the Caesar cipher is easily broken and in modern practice offers essentially no communication security

Answer (score 2):

This is simplest encrypt/decrypt code but it is not secure.

```
     String strip = "192.168.1.11";        
     byte[] encryptArray = Base64.encodeBase64(strip.getBytes());        
     String encstr = new String(encryptArray,"UTF-8");   
     System.out.println("Enc   >>  "+ encstr);


     String strDec = "MTkyLjE2OC4xLjEx";
     byte[] dectryptArray = strDec.getBytes();
     byte[] decarray = Base64.decodeBase64(dectryptArray);
     String decstr = new String(decarray,"UTF-8"); 
     System.out.println("Dec  >>>  "+ decstr);
```

For this you have to *`import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;`*

you can **Download org-apache-commons-codec.jar** file from [Link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonscodecjar.htm)

Comment: Simple and easy.. Thanks!!

Comment: since java 8, you can use the Base64 that is part of the JDK. `java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(string.getBytes());`

Answer (score 1):

If the generated string would be "random", then your application would have to keep track of any generated string for all time. Probably not a good design.

A fast poor man "encryption" would be ROT47 ( http://rot47.net/ )

Comment: It's for letters, not for decimals

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I actually thought of ROT47; but confused myself. ROT47 will work for numbers, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple random encryption:

```
class SimpleStringEncryption {

  public static String encrypt(String str){
    int code;
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      code = Math.round((float) Math.random()*8+1);
      result += code + Integer.toHexString( ((int) str.charAt(i) ) ^ code )+"-";
    }
    return result.substring(0, result.lastIndexOf("-"));
  }

  public static String decrypt(String str){
    str = str.replace("-", "");
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i+=3) {
      String hex =  str.substring(i+1, i+3);
      result += (char) (Integer.parseInt(hex, 16) ^ (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)))));
    }
    return result;
  }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String e = "some text to encrypt";
        String encrypted = encrypt(e);
        System.out.println(encrypted);
        System.out.println(decrypt(encrypted));
    }  

}
```

hope this helps.