# Can't overcome the javax.crypto.BadPaddingException

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, steganography, badpaddingexception

I'm writing a steganography system which encrypt a text within an image - i decided that i want to encrypt the text as well before i embed it in the picture. The Steganography algorithm works with String input/output.

Due to my whim, i've been trying to use DES and AES algorithm but ran into the Exception above. i'll show for example the encryption/decryption methods of the AES algorithm:

```
    public static byte[] encryptText(String plainText,SecretKey secKey) throws Exception{
    // AES defaults to AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in Java 7
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);
    byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
    return byteCipherText;}


    public static String decryptText(byte[] byteCipherText, SecretKey secKey) throws Exception {
    // AES defaults to AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in Java 7
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secKey);
    byte[] bytePlainText = aesCipher.doFinal(byteCipherText);
    return new String(bytePlainText);
}
```

And here is the calling (Encryption side):

```
  //sending the text to encrypt using AES algorithm
byte[] cipherText = new AES_Algorithm().encrypt(messageDesc.getText(), key);
  //converting into a String to encrypt using Steganography
newStringtoEncrypt = new String (cipherText);
```

And here is the calling (Decryption side) - **THE EXCEPTION**:

```
  //AES encrypted String after the Steganography's decryption 
String decMessage = dec.decode(path, name);
  //converting the String to byte []
byte [] byteArray = decMessage.getBytes();
try{
    //HERE IS WHERE I GET THE EXCEPTION
    //sending the byte array to decryption
  String original = AES_Algorithm().decrypt(byteArray, key);
```

Where is the problem?

The keys are similar and the byte arrays as well (i checked it by printing the sequence) - but i have been told that i can't use `getBytes()` in order to convert from String to `byteArray` when i intend to use `AES/DES` decryption algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from the encryption is binary, you can't just convert it to `String` as you do in this code:

```
byte[] cipherText = new AES_Algorithm().encrypt(messageDesc.getText(), key);
//converting into a String to encrypt using Steganography
newStringtoEncrypt = new String (cipherText);
```

If you need the encrypted data as `String`, you need to encode it somehow, e.g. by [base64encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743851/base64-java-encode-and-decode-a-string) or by [hexEncoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java)

Comment: My GOD, how simple... i've been racking my brain for 2 days now - THANK YOU!