# Load image in a String and save after change image

Tags: java, image, image-processing, stream

I'm trying load an image in a string and after do something with this String, save the image.

The problem appear when i try to asignate the value of the FileInputStream to the String targetFileStr. If i don't to this, and I save the image, everything it's ok, but when i save it on the String, the image change, no matter if I try save the image from the String or from the FileInputStream.

```
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    File file = new File("image.png");
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    String targetFileStr = IOUtils.toString(fis, "UTF-8");

    *InputStream inputStream =  IOUtils.toInputStream(targetFileStr, "UTF-8");
    *InputStream inputStream = fis;
    // no matter which one i use, both ways fail

    OutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {

        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("image2.png"));

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You can't load an image in a string.

Comment: For what reason? if I can load it onto a FileInputStream I can convert this to a String. do not?

Comment: The "do not" is correct.  Unless as suggested below you want an encoded binary image of some sort, then there's no way a random image is going to be able to be interpreted as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider converting the image into a String via Base64 encoding/decoding. [This is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743851/base64-java-encode-and-decode-a-string) of encoding.

After encoding, you can modify the String (actually you create new strings, you cannot modify the existing one), but be sure to produce valide base64-encoded outputs, otherwise you won't be able to decode.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see what you told me. on the other hand I have been converting the string to byte [] and making operations needed there, but it seems easier with base64