# JAVA DES Encryption Output Encoding

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, utf-8

I have DES Encryption Algorithm implementation in JAVA (javax.crypto.Cipher), it is successfully encoding and decoding (most) strings... the problem is that, sometimes, it message specific blocks (since DES uses 8-character blocks in block mode).

In my case, almost always the 3rd block is messed up and rest shows fine.

for example:

key: `thisiskey`

message to encrypt: `Google is an American multinational technology company specializing in Internet-related services`

encrypted message (in UTF-8):

```
mñqè•ÀPŒ�øf"
ß¦\±õ¤ù'È9¢ëyT ÍQEÁ|;ëâÉ÷JWú
```

Now, when i go and decrypt this, i get this:

Decrypted message:

```
Google i,í\O¯‹Ýbº-¸�¬ltinational technology company specializHôJ—=ÊÍnternet-related services
```

As far as i understand the issue, it is due to the fact that UTF-8 CANNOT show all characters and thus, while showing as well as copying for decryption, this problem occurs.

Can anyone suggest me a solution?
Preferably, either a character-set that can handle this, or, a way to convert Binary directly to HEX (that can be output to user) and then Vice Versa (decrypted, after copying/pasting) in JAVA.

**EDIT**
This is 'approximate' code, not exact (for example encrypted message is not properly paste-able and these are parts of the function, but it should give the idea). Even in base64 encoding , i am unable to get this decrypted properly.

```
Encrypt Function code:

boolean base64 = true;
key = "thisiskey";
plainText = "Google is an American multinational technology company specializing in Internet-related services";

SecretKeyFactory MyKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes();

DESKeySpec generatedKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(keyBytes);
SecretKey generatedSecretKey = MyKeyFactory.generateSecret(generatedKeySpec);

Cipher generatedCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
generatedCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, generatedSecretKey);

byte[] messsageStringBytes = plainText.getBytes();
byte[] encryptedMessage = generatedCipher.doFinal(messsageStringBytes);

String encryptedMessageString = new String(encryptedMessage);

if (base64) {
    encryptedMessageString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedMessageString.getBytes("utf-8"));
}

return encryptedMessageString;
```

Decrypt Function code:

```
boolean dbase64 = true;
dkey = "thisiskey";
messageToDecrypt = "mñqè•ÀPŒ�øf\"ß¦\±õ¤ù'È9¢ëyT ÍQEÁ|;ëâÉ÷JWú"; // Message from above code

SecretKeyFactory MyKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
byte[] dkeyBytes = dkey.getBytes();

DESKeySpec generatedKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(dkeyBytes);
SecretKey generatedSecretKey = MyKeyFactory.generateSecret(generatedKeySpec);

Cipher generatedCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
generatedCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, generatedSecretKey);

if (dbase64) {
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(dencryptedText);
    dencryptedText = new String(decodedBytes, "utf-8");
}

byte[] messsageStringBytes = dencryptedText.getBytes();
byte[] encryptedMessage = generatedCipher.doFinal(messsageStringBytes);

String decryptedMessageString = new String(encryptedMessage);

return decryptedMessageString;
```

Comment: How could you possibly expect anyone to be able to help you without your code?

Comment: DES is a great encryption algorithm—if security is not required. DES has been superseded by AES, use AES. Please don't create bad security, we have enough already.

Answer (score 2):

"Encrypted message in UTF-8" makes no sense. The ciphertext is binary and not UTF-8. You need to put it into a `byte[]`, not a `String`.

If you need a String, use [Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743851/base64-java-encode-and-decode-a-string?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java) encoding.

---

> Even in base64 encoding , i am unable to get this decrypted properly.

```
String encryptedMessageString = new String(encryptedMessage);

if (base64) {
  encryptedMessageString =  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedMessageString.getBytes("utf-8"));
}
```

That does not work. You are encoding to Base64 after the data is already broken (by calling `new String`). Do not put it in a String at all. Go directly from `encryptedMessage` (the `byte[]`) to Base64.

Comment: So, how do you suggest i 'show' the text for using/copying? can you help a bit please?

Comment: If you need a String, use Base64 or Hex encoding. See the linked threads for details.