# Base64 Encoding: Illegal base64 character 3c

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, base64, decoding

I am trying to decode data in an xml format into bytes `base64` and I am having an issues. My method is in java which takes a `String` data and converts it into `bytes` like as bellow.

```
String data = "......"; //string of data in xml format
byte[] dataBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);
```

Which failed and gave the exception like bellow.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3c
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714)
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
    at XmlReader.main(XmlReader.java:61)
```

Is the xml format not compatible with `base64`?

Comment: well, what is `data`?

Comment: it looks something like this:

<Version description="....." productname="....." productversion="1.0" validvalues="....">1.0</Version>

Comment: That is **not** a base64 encoded String.

Comment: how can it be changed to a base64 string? Do I need to use encode?

Comment: Yes, of course. You have some human readable data like the one you have shown so far, then you `encode` it to base64 which will only have the allowed base64 chars, then you `decode` that base64 string into the original content again.

Comment: `DataString -> encode -> Base64String -> decode -> DataString`

Comment: so something like:

            byte[] dataBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(data.getBytes());

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743851/base64-java-encode-and-decode-a-string

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: Adding that you may also get this if you try to decode a "URL-safe" base64 string using the regular `Base64.getDecoder()` - in that case you have to use a utility that can handle such strings, e.g. `org.springframework.util.Base64Utils.decodeFromUrlSafeString()`

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Thanks to @luk2302 I was able to resolve the issue. Before decoding the string, I need to first encode it to Base64

```
    byte[] dataBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(data.getBytes());
    dataBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(dataBytes);
```

Comment: Are you just encoding text and decoding it right away? If so, I fail to understand what's achieved through this.

Comment: Probably the encode function is correcting the encoding mismatch that is not making the conversion work at first instance

Comment: @funder7 With this you end up with the *original (encoded)* string, not the real decoded value - encoded (by someone else) -> encoded (by you) -> decoded (by you) = encoded (by someone else); i.e. the original

Answer (score 45):

Just use this method

> getMimeDecoder()

```
String data = "......";
byte[] dataBytes =  Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(data);
```

Comment: In deed this works, though I'm curious what's the difference between those 2 APIs, docs are not quite helpful.

Comment: @azizbekian Mime decoder allows for illegal characters while trying to decode a Base64 string.

Answer (score 6):

I got this same error and problem was that the string was starting with `data:image/png;base64, ...`

The solution was:

```
byte[] imgBytes = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(imgBase64.split(",")[1]);
```

Comment: And this is what I did `resp = resp.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");`

Answer (score 2):

You should first get the bytes out of the string (in some character encoding).

For these bytes you use the encoder to create the Base64 representation for that bytes.

This Base64 string can then be decoded back to bytes and with the same encoding you convert these bytes to a string.

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Base64Example {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String xml = "<root-node><sub-node/></root-node>";
    final byte[] xmlBytes = xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final String xmlBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(xmlBytes);
    System.out.println(xml);
    System.out.println(xmlBase64);

    final byte[] xmlBytesDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(xmlBase64);
    final String xmlDecoded = new String(xmlBytesDecoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(xmlDecoded);
  }

}
```

Output is:

```
<root-node><sub-node/></root-node>
PHJvb3Qtbm9kZT48c3ViLW5vZGUvPjwvcm9vdC1ub2RlPg==
<root-node><sub-node/></root-node>
```