# Read url encoded data in spring boot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, url-encoding

I have a source which calls a post api and the request is url encoded. How can I retrieve the request data that is url encoded using spring boot.

### Update

In my controller I have below method,

```
@PostMapping(value = "/res", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public Map<String, Object> postResponse(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> url) {...}
```

It returns error

> "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
>       "message": "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported"

How can I get form-urlencoded data in controller

Comment: Use URLDecoder.decode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
or use Base64 encoder and decoder
Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19743925/540195

Comment: At least show us what you have done so far or even take time to write a snippet demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer finally.

url encoded values can be read as String

```
@PostMapping(value = "/res", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public Map<String, Object> postResponse(@RequestBody String request) {...}
```