# Can we add ByteArrayInputStream in JobManager?

Tags: aem, sling

AEM6.2
I have a Osgi Service where in `org.apache.sling.event.jobs.JobManager` referenced and job is added to it.

The code is something like:

```
Map dataSourceMap = new HashMap<String, DataSource>
dataSourceMap.put(fileName, new ByteArrayDataSource(byte[], mimeTypeOfFile))

final Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
props.put("item1", "/something");
props.put("count", 5);
props.put("files", dataSourceMap)

jobManager.addJob("my/special/jobtopic", props);
```

When this job gets executed it shows some error

```
org.apache.sling.api.resource.PersistenceException: Value can't be stored in the repository: {<<filename>>=org.apache.commons.mail.ByteArrayDataSource@3f0f234c}
```

Question: Is there any solution to this exception? Or am I doing something wrong? can we add a ByteArrayInputStream to the jobmanager?

Thank you !

Just a info, If I remove the line `props.put("files", dataSourceMap)`, it works fine.

Please let me know if you need more info on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sling will store the job as a node in the repository and it looks like it only supports the "standard" types like `String`, `Boolean`, `Integer` etc. and not files/blobs.

I can not think of a way to add a file to the job, but what you could do is to create temporary node in the repository yourself, which contains the files/blobs.

Sling stores jobs here:

`/var/eventing/jobs`

You might do something similar:

`/var/<project-name>/jobs`

And the payload of the Sling job then contains the path to this job node.

Comment: Thanks Jens ! 
That make sense , but some how I'm trying to store blob/files into an object and try to store that object in sling jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Jens' comment, the job will indeed store data as node properties in the JCR. You could likely explore the possibility of storing data as `Binary` to the `jcr:data` property, but I have not tested this myself.

As a quick and likely not very optimized workaround, why not serialize your `byte[]` to a `String` or even encode it to a Base64 string?

Sample: [Base64 Java encode and decode a string [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743851/base64-java-encode-and-decode-a-string)

Comment: Thanks ! this also works fine but seems to be just a work around.