# Receiving percentage encoded url

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, uri, urlencode

I am invoking a GET method on a percentage encoded URI , but my rest controller is not able to handle it. It throws Internal Server Error. How am i suppose to handle encoded uri on rest controller side using @RequestParam

Comment: try to put some code that you've tried before !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use String in @RequestBody, and use [URLDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) to decode in UTF-8.
Like this - `URLDecoder.decode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())`.
You can use base64 as well. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743851/base64-java-encode-and-decode-a-string/19743925#19743925) answer.