# Storing a JSON payload in ByteBuffer is unable to print braces or colon

Tags: java, json, base64

I have a JSON payload encoded to Base64 that needs to be stored in a ByteBuffer to be returned.
Upon trying to convert it from Base64 to JSON on base64decode.org I am able to get the proper json but on trying to do the same in code, it just prints out the data but not the `{`, `}` or the `:`
I am using `DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary` to achieve it.
What should I use in the code to return the properly formatted JSON payload?

Comment: Please show the code you have written, including how you print the output, an example of the input, and the output.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743851/base64-java-encode-and-decode-a-string