# How to convert base64 to string in spring-boot(java)

Tags: java, spring-boot

How to  convert base64 to string in spring-boot(java).
My private key in base64 format i want to convert it to string format. I don't know how to do this please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: [Java Base64 encode decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743851/base64-java-encode-and-decode-a-string), This may answer your question

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode

Comment: *My private key in base64 format i want to convert it to string format.* But (proper) private keys are *not* strings, which is *why* they are stored base64-encoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand encoding/decoding if you want to customize it but simply you can use **Base64 class** of Java to decode from Base64 to String. Given an example -

```
byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode("Your String");
String decodedString = new String(decode);
```

You can check **java.util.Base64** class to find out more interesting thing.

Reference - https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode